# What is the correct syntax to the -Context parameter of EF 7's Add-Migration command?

Tags: entity-framework-core

Using the latest pre-release version of EntityFramework 7 (v7.0.0-rc1-final), I have tried to use the `Add-Migration` PowerShell command through the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio; I have tried to add migrations to my DAL.

With a folder structure that looks something like:

```
-Project
  -DAL
    -Context.cs
```

I have tried variations of the following command:

`Add-Migration Initial -OutputDir DAL\Migrations -Context ContextClassName`

Including, but not limited to:

`Add-Migration Initial -OutputDir DAL\Migrations -Context Project.Namespace.DAL.ContextClassName`

`Add-Migration Initial -OutputDir DAL\Migrations -Context DAL\Context.cs`

To no avail...

The package for the tools is installed like so:

`Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Pre`

The [docs](http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/miscellaneous/cli/powershell.html#add-migration) are less than helpful and `Get-Help Add-Migration -Examples` and `-Full`, `-Detailed` etc. give you nothing relating to the expected format of the `-Context` parameter.

What is the correct format?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're using the wrong EF7 package! [As per the announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/144), there's no longer an Entity Framework 7 but only EntityFrameworkCore.

As per your linked documentation and specifically following the documentation section for [Full DotNet](http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/platforms/full-dotnet/new-db.html) You need to reference `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.*` and not EntityFramework.* (for EF7)

Following the instructions of above page and issuing:

`Add-Migration -OutputDir DAL\Migrations -Context ContextClassName`

I have no issue getting the migration sorted.

Comment: Thank you. You helped me resolved an issue by running `PM> Add-Migration MyFirstMigration -Context BloggingContext` for a Microsoft example of ASP.NET Core 1.0 project on VS2015- Update 3` released on June 27, 2016.

Comment: Cheers dude, it did help :)