# ASP.NET Core EF Add-Migration command not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Following this [Microsoft Tutorial](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html#create-your-database) when I run the `PM> Add-Migration MyFirstMigration` command in VS2015 project created from the same tutorial I get the following error that I can't resolve:

> More than one DbContext was found. Specify which one to use.
>   Use the '-Context' parameter for PowerShell commands and the
>   '--context' parameter for dotnet commands.

**Point to note**

1. I'm using the above tutorial with the exception that I'm using `Individual User Account` authentication instead of `No Authentication` used in the tutorial.
2. I've latest release of `ASP.NeT Core 1.0 and VS2015-Update 3 on windows 8.1`
3. This is a freshly created project. No other DbContext was manually installed

Comment: The error text is describing the reason and what should you do.

Comment: Also, the code should be part of the question. The link is broken, rendering the question into an empty shell.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Running the following command (obtained from [this article](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/#Add-Migration)) and a response from @Maverik (from StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38126823/1232087)) and a suggestion from @doctor above helped me resolved the issue. Thank you all for your help:

```
PM> Add-Migration MyFirstMigration -Context BloggingContext
```

Comment: meanwhile the `-Context` changed to `-c` from what i could test

Comment: It should be `--context` in .net core 2.0.

Comment: is it possible that several contexts are same in **name** but diff only in **namespace**?

Answer (score 19):

The error clearly explains to mention --context with db Context name if more than one DbContext. So try by mentioning your DbContext name.

```
dotnet ef migrations add Initial --context SampleDbContext
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Isn't the issue that there are multiple db contexts? Do we need multiple contexts? How do we identify & delete them??

Comment: no. This is not an issue with multiple db contexts. We can use multiple db contexts, for example in multi tenant architecture it requires multiple db contexts. So there are situations where multiple db contexts required.

Comment: Didn't list what to do if you have multiple contexts. What if I have 10? Do I list `--context` 10 times???

Answer (score 16):

If you need only update a identity schema existent, try it:

```
update-database -Context ApplicationDbContext
```

ApplicationDbContext = your identity context

Answer (score 4):

that because you have two DbContext in your solution. First is default created when you creating project(ApplicationDbContext) and second your EF DbContext.
Solution is described in error message just specify your EF DbContext

Answer (score 2):

`Add-Migration MyFirstMigration -Context DbContextName`

It does work in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Use below to commands:

> PM> Add-Migration MyFirstMigration -Context YourDbContext
>
> PM> update-database -Context YourDbContext

Comment: what is the difference between Add-Migration and dotnet ef  Initial Migration?

Answer (score 1):

**[--context]**

> The DbContext class to use. Class name only or fully qualified with
> namespaces. If this option is omitted, EF Core will find the context
> class. If there are multiple context classes, this option is required.

```
Add-Migration MyMigration -context DataContextName
```