# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Identity add new model - table to the Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a started a new ASP.NET Core 2.0 project and I use the the Entity Framework with Identity.

The starting database schema consists from the following tables:

[image]

Everything works as expected with the current schema and I didn't have any problems with the existing datatable operations.

Now I want to alter the database schema. I want to add some new tables but I am finding it difficult to find some documentation to help me understand the way to do it.

For now I am following the "[Create an app with user data protected by authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data#create-the-starter-app)" and I started from [creating a new model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model) to my application.

After creating a new model and scaffolding the Controller for this model a new Context was created in my appsettings.json. I just had the DefaultConnection and now was added the esendContext.

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-esend-069757D7-82B1-4850-8015-07D7D54AA712;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
"esendContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=esendContext-25459d27-29ec-4943-ac91-6b9cb91a0dd6;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

When I hit the new url I get the following message:

[image]

I understand that I should apply the migrations but I wonder why do I get the `SqlException: Cannot open database ....` error

Furthermore when I try to apply the migration (Add-Migration Initial -Context esendContext according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38162227/asp-net-core-ef-add-migration-command-not-working) since I got an error about the context I should use) according to documentation in the PMC

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
Add-Migration Initial
Update-Database
```

when I try to update the database I get

> An error occurred while calling method 'BuildWebHost' on class
>   'Program'. Continuing without the application service provider. Error:
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore,
>   Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
>   The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> No DbContext was found in assembly 'esend'. Ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic.

I am not really sure If this is the procedure I should be following. 
Any help or link for something that could help would be greatly appreciated and excuse me If I have stated too many issues in one question.

Comment: Do you have more than one project in your solution?

Comment: @S.Akbari No I just have one project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I saw my error was related to the version of the Microsoft.AspNetCore.All I was using which was 2.0.0.

According to [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10287) and bricelam's answer I updated to version 2.0.3 which was the latest available and the migration was completed correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your .csproj has that node :

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

and i don't know what do you mean by this :
"After creating a new model and scaffolding the Controller for this model a new Context was created in my appsettings.json."

but if you are using asp identity then your project has a DbContext already and you don't need a new One !